# How to Draw Text on an image within a form on Mouse Click Event in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics, drawing

I want to draw a text within an image in C# by using the method drawstring.But how can i obtain the co-ordinates of the clicked position and how can i relate this to the dimension of the image.
Please Help.

Comment: you may see this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710643/improve-the-performance-of-a-panel-onmousemove-method-for-a-signature-control][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:

```
private Bitmap _bmp = new Bitmap(250, 250);

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();   

  panel1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseDown);
  panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);

  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_bmp))
    g.Clear(SystemColors.Window);
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(_bmp, new Point(0, 0));

}

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_bmp))
  {
    g.DrawString("Mouse Clicked Here!", panel1.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Location);
  }
  panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

You might want to use TextRenderer instead of DrawString.  DrawString has issues.

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "Mouse Clicked Here!", panel1.Font, e.Location, Color.Black);
```

Comment: Still its not working.I have created a form and placed a panel named panel1 and placed the code that you provided in the required event.

Comment: @rainbower Make sure the events are hooked up.  You can do that through the designer, but I updated the code to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this, I'd follow this guy's tutorial;

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/09/02/click-image-and-get-coordinates-with-javascript/

and in his function, generate an ajax post-back with the co-ordinates in the querystring. Then do whatever you need to do with them. You would be better off using client side scripting for this sort of thing though.

Comment: Thanks,But im talking about C# not JScript